# Decompose a fraction into a sum of fractions (with complex variable)

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, fractions

Here is equality:

$\frac{1}{z\ln4+(z\ln4)^2/2+O(z^3)}=\frac{1}{z\ln4}-\frac{1}{2}+O(z)$

I can't understand why is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\require{cancel}\frac1{1+u}=1-u+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as  $z \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z\ln4+(z\ln4)^2/2+O(z^3)}&=\frac{1}{z\ln4}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\underbrace{\frac{\ln4}2\cdot z+O(z^2)}_{\color{red}{u \,\text{with}\, u\to 0}}}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{z\ln4}\cdot\left[1-\left(\frac{\ln4}2\cdot z+O(z^2)\right)+O(z^2)\right]
\\\\&=\frac{1}{z\ln4}-\frac{1}{\cancel{z}\cancel{\ln4}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{\ln4}}2\cdot \cancel{z}+O(z)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{z\ln4}-\frac12+O(z).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes, I do :)
Thank you so much!

Comment: @ДмитрийСухов You are welcome.